# Oracle SQL query to Convert Indian date to Saudi Arabian date

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement of displaying Saudi Arabian date in a field.
Currently it is displaying Indian date format.I need a SQL query to convert Indian date to Arabian date format.

Can somebody help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried some convert or the cast functions? Which type has your field?

Comment: what is Arabian Format like dd/MM/yyyy ? https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156 , this may aslo helps  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: Do you mean converting from Gregorian (1st Jan 2018) to Islamic Calendar (Rabi Al-Thani 13, 1439) ? Or simply 'yyyy/mm/dd' to 'dd/mm/yyyy' or such like format changes?

Comment: What is the data type? Do you have some example data?